# Customize queryset in django-filter ModelChoiceFilter (select) and ModelMultipleChoiceFilter (multi-select) menus based on request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/) in 2 places: My [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) API, and in my [FilterViews](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#generic-view-configuration) (Django Filter's Generic ListViews.) In the case of my FilterViews I'm showing both select boxes ([ModelChoiceFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter-and-modelmultiplechoicefilter-arguments)) and multi-select boxes (ModelMultipleChoiceFilter) to be filtered on.

I need to be able to limit what's in those select and multi-select inputs based on a field inside the request.

It's relatively simple to change what's listed as a kwarg in the relevant field in the FilterSet. For example, here's my FilterSet where the queryset is set as a kwarg:

```
class FieldFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    """Filter for the field list in the API"""
    dataset = ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Dataset.objects.all())

    class Meta(object):
        """Meta options for the filter"""
         model = Field
         fields = ['dataset']
```

And it's relatively straightforward to limit what the **result** is in DRF inside the `get_queryset()` method. For example, here's my DRF ViewSet:

```
class FieldViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """A ViewSet for viewing dataset fields"""
    queryset = Field.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FieldSerializer
    filter_class = FieldFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Get the queryset"""
        queryset = super(FieldViewSet, self).get_queryset()

        queryset = queryset.filter(
            dataset__organization=self.request.organization)

        return queryset
```

I just can't find anywhere to edit the `Dataset` field in the `filter_class` when the view is being displayed.

This is super straightforward in Django `FormView` generic views, but it doesn't appear that `FieldViewSet` follows the same `get_form()` structure as generic views. It's also relatively straightforward to do in the admin, but DRF/Django-Filter don't seem to follow that structure either.

Is there any way to customize the queryset in those inputs on a per-request basis? Preferably both on FilterViews and in the HTML API browser, but just in FilterViews would be fine if it's too complicated for the HTML API browser.

Comment: Can you post a snippet? This is easily done in django admin and I suppose it would be very similar.

Comment: Added some code examples of what I tried. What works in the admin doesn't appear to work here.

Comment: So the `get_queryset()` function is the right filtering that you want to use inside `FieldFilter` ?

Comment: Yep, and that's correctly filtering the result in DRF, but it's not filtering out the filter options in the DRF HTMLView

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of search, I found the solution in the official documentation [here](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/usage.html#filtering-the-related-queryset-for-modelchoicefilter)!

The queryset argument for `ModelChoiceFilter` and `ModelMultipleChoiceFilter` supports callable behavior. If a callable is passed, it will be invoked with the `request` as its only argument.

```
import django_filters as filters
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

def ourBranches(request):
    if request is None:
        return Branch.objects.none()

    company = request.user.profile.company
    return Branch.objects.filter(company=company)


class UnitFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    branch = filters.ModelChoiceFilter(
        queryset=ourBranches, empty_label=_("All Branches"))

    class Meta:
        model = Unit
        fields = ('branch', )
```

and in the view, I made sure to pass the `request` as well

```
 qs = Unit.objects.all()
 filter = UnitFilter(self.request.GET, request=self.request, queryset=qs) 
 table = UnitTable(filter.qs)
```

Answer (score 3):

I also had problems finding a resolution to this.

I solved it (I think) via the following:

**views.py**

```
table_filter = ExampleFilter(request.GET, kwarg_I_want_to_pass=request.user, queryset=qs)
```

**filters.py**

```
class ExampleFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('kwarg_I_want_to_pass', None)
        super(ExampleFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.filters['field_to_filter'].extra.update({
           'queryset': Supplier.objects.filter(related_user=self.user),
           'empty_label': '',
           'help_text': False
        })

    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = ['related_user', 'field_to_filter', ... other fields]
```

Comment: Not working with me, still gets `.all()` of the model!